# Getting an error when trying to publish .net 5 web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, deployment, .net-5

I got this error when I published my web application to IIS.

Title : HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

[image]

I viewed most questions on this and all saying that I should install a hosting bundle and I did install the latest one according to my targeted framework and still facing this.

### What I tried:

- 1-the application works fine on IIS Express from VS.
- 2-I published the application from web deploy to the local IIS and I
  tried
  on both modes self-contained and framework-dependent.
- 3-installed hosting bundle.
- 4-changing hosts files and it works fine even on other .net frameworks
  sites.
- 5-web config is okay, I couldn't get the wrong configs in
  applicationhost.config .

after all, I still facing the error. please help, thanks

Comment: Run a report to get started please, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: In app pool, make sure .NET framework is not selected.

Comment: yes , sure I created a new one

Comment: Event viewer may contain some records related to error, try to check it out

Comment: Recently I noticed that after installing the hosting bundle I couldn't found aspnetCore listed in modules , Any one knows why ??and how can I fix this.

Comment: Did you get the hosting bundle from correct [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.7-windows-hosting-bundle-installer) of Microsoft? When the installation is complete, restart IIS.

Comment: Have you tried to check and list the installed .NET runtimes using `dotnet --list-runtimes`?

Comment: 500 internal is generic error, please double check your code again. Maybe this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/asp-net-core-hosting-3-simple-steps-to-fix-502-5-error-in-asp-net-core/ can also be good reference for you.

Comment: yes @BruceZhang  and the same configs worked on other server but (win server 2016 )

Comment: I will re install IIS I noticed its not updating the IIS Folder to add the aspnetcore Module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it Works,
This what I did :

- Uninstall IIS , Remove IIS Folder from Program Files and install It again
- Install Hosting Bundle [from here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.7-windows-hosting-bundle-installer)
- I Checked the IIS Folder and I found aspnetCore module
- Added the published version both modes worked for me (self -contained or framework-dependent)

the problem was that the installation didn't add aspnetcore modules to previous IIS Folder